# Setting a third party cookie in PHP

Tags: php, iframe, cookies

I have a site that is using an iframe to load a power outage map from a power company's website. The power company's site uses a cookie to remember a user's state to show the correct map. I'd like to have my own site send this cookie with the geographic location to the external site in the iframe for users who have not set their location. Is this possible to do?
ex.

`setcookie("GeographicLocation","%2FGeographic%20Location%2FColorado",$time,"/","www.powercompany.com");`

Answer (score 3):

No. You cannot set cookies on behalf of third-party sites, regardless of whether you're embedding them in an iframe. If browsers allowed this it would be a severe security hole.

Comment: It would be catastrophic :)